# Set filename for WritetoFiles

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

My flow stores files on disk and I need to set the filename so I can find things back.

The default naming is the window timestamps and a counter and this does not help me. Documentation is not clear enough for me. (https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.16.0/apache_beam.io.fileio.html?highlight=default_file_naming)

```
fileio.WriteToFiles(archive_storage, file_naming=beam.io.fileio.destination_prefix_naming())
```

I want to name the files `<HASH>.json` where the HASH is that of the data withtin the file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to get a working snippet thanks to [this example](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/io/fileio_test.py). In this case we'll specify a different `destination` for each record according to their hash as we want to write each element to a different file. In addition, we'll pass our custom naming function called `hash_naming`:

```py
data = [{'id': 0, 'message': 'hello'},
        {'id': 1, 'message': 'world'}]

(p
  | 'Create Events' >> beam.Create(data) \
  | 'JSONify' >> beam.Map(json.dumps) \
  | 'Print Hashes' >> beam.ParDo(PrintHashFn()) \
  | 'Write Files' >> fileio.WriteToFiles(
      path='./output',
      destination=lambda record: hash(record),
      sink=lambda dest: JsonSink(),
      file_naming=hash_naming))
```

In `PrintHashFn` we'll log each element with each hash:

```py
logging.info("Element: %s with hash %s", element, hash(element))
```

so that, for our data, we'll get:

```py
INFO:root:Element: {"message": "hello", "id": 0} with hash -1885604661473532601
INFO:root:Element: {"message": "world", "id": 1} with hash 9144125507731048840
```

There might be a better way but I found out that invoking `fileio.destination_prefix_naming()(*args)` we can retrieve the destination (`-1885604661473532601`) from the default naming scheme (`-1885604661473532601----00000-00001`):

```py
def hash_naming(*args):
  file_name = fileio.destination_prefix_naming()(*args)  # -1885604661473532601----00000-00001
  destination = file_name.split('----')[0]  # -1885604661473532601
  return '{}.json'.format(destination)  # -1885604661473532601.json
```

Note that the split to get the substring might be different in your case if you add windowing into the mix.

Running the script with 2.16.0 SDK and the `DirectRunner` I get the following output:

```sh
$ ls output/
-1885604661473532601.json  9144125507731048840.json
$ cat output/-1885604661473532601.json 
"{\"message\": \"hello\", \"id\": 0}"
```

Updated full code [here](https://gist.github.com/gxercavins/5154339708317025cf084a70a84fe4f9).

Comment: I took out the JsonSink(), don't know what it should do. This hashes the filename and that is nice but I will not be able to find back my data with it, I was aiming to hash the data within the file. I will improve my question to make this clear.

Comment: Yes, if I understand it correctly that's what I was trying to show. Anyway, I modified it with a couple small JSON elements as data and passing only the hash of the record to the filename. For example, `{"message": "hello", "id": 0}` has hash `-1885604661473532601` so it will be written to `-1885604661473532601.json`. Regarding `JsonSink()` I just took it from the other example, remember that you can check the full code here: https://gist.github.com/gxercavins/5154339708317025cf084a70a84fe4f9#file-script-py-L9